# How To Mount A Disk Image On Android With Terminal?

Tags: terminal, mount, android, disk-image, loopback

I'm trying to mount a disk image that I've made on my android with terminal and busybox. This is how I made the image:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/sdcard/disk.img bs=4k count=131072    

mkfs.vfat -v /sdcard/disk.img
```

And now I'm trying to mount it. I've read a lot about loopback devices but I can't figure it out. Does anyone know how to mount a disk image in android using terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following command on terminal :

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop "<path>/image.iso" /mnt
```

Your ISO image will be accessible under /mnt

Additionally if it's img file :

```
mkdir ~/img

mount -t udf filename.img ~/img -o loop
```

Comment: It's not an iso.

Comment: @JaïrPaalman updated answer

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but I get the error ioctl LOOP_SET_FD failed: Device or resource busy. Also, shouldn't I use vfat as type since I formatted the file with mkfs.vfat and is that enough since I didn't use fdisk to partition anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969516/android-linuxioctl-loop-set-fd-failed

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 and if the raw disk image contains partitions? How do I create the devices required for mapping them?